# A query to search on the whole model [Laravel]

Tags: jquery, sql, laravel, models

I want some query to **search on all of [User] Model** for example !!

That I can give it an input and search for it on all User's columns ..

is there some thing like that ?

Comment: Please, specify your table and code!

Comment: Searching on every column in a table for something is probably not the best idea, at least not in a production environment.

Comment: I want a query to search for some $Input on users table ,,

not in specific column but on the whole table !!

Is my question clear enough now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add a where like for every column in the table:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');
$query = User::query();
$search = Input::get('search');
foreach($columns as $column){
    $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
}
$users = $query->get();
```